# How can I pass the selected contact between two components

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make the user to be able to select a contact from the contacts component and the chatroom of that user and the contact get displayed in the chatroom component. It was working fine when I was using dummy data in a user.ts file but since I added the backend and stuff think are not working well.

So I made use here of the Input and Output decorator and event emitter bindings to handle that, but noticed the chatroom still doesn't get the value of the selectedContact.

What happends is the chats is the parent of the chatroom and the contacts
The contacts emits an event with the contact slected when its selected and the chats captures that and outputs the selectedContact to the chatroom but it doesn't work.

Here's the chats.html:

```
<div class="row h-100 w-100 mx-0 px-0">
  <!-- Contacts -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 px-0 h-100" [class.d-none]="selectedContact && isMobile">
    <app-contacts (contactSelected)="selectContact($event)"></app-contacts>
  </div>
  <!-- Chatroom -->
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 px-0 h-100" [class.d-none]="!selectedContact && isMobile">
    <app-chatroom [selectedContact]="selectedContact" (goBackClicked)="selectContact(null)"></app-chatroom>
  </div>
</div>
```

chats.ts: (summerized)

```
@Output() selectedContact: any | null = null;
  selectContact(contact: any | null) {
  this.selectedContact = contact;
}
```

Now the contacts.html: (summerized)

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of filteredContacts" class="chat" (click)="selectContact(contact)">
```

contact.ts:

```
@Output() contactSelected = new EventEmitter<any>();
  selectContact(contact: any) {
  this.contactSelected.emit(contact);
}
```

Now the chatroom.ts:

```
@Input() selectedContact: any | null = null;
@Output() goBackClicked = new EventEmitter<void>();
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.selectedContact)
    if(this.selectedContact){
      const userId = this.userService.getUser().pipe(map(user => user._id));
      console.log(this.selectedContact)
      const contactId = this.selectedContact._id;

      this.chatService.getSelectedContactMessages(userId, contactId).subscribe(
      (messages: any[]) => {
        this.selectedContact.messages = messages;
        this.scrollToBottom();
      },
      (error) => {
        this.alertService.showError(error.error.error);
      }
   );
  }
}
goBack() {
 this.goBackClicked.emit();
}
```

I observed also that immediately I load the app the ngAfterViewInit funs and prints null to the browser console, which I expect it to only run when the user has selected a contact, also on mobile the contacts show and the chatroom hides until a contact is selected the chatroom shows and the contact hides so how can I make this work.
Please you guys are my last hope to make this work tried to solve this with 4 different AIs for the past 3 days to no avail, sorry if it's long or mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is OK, but you're trying to reach updated data through the wrong way.

**use ngOnChanges in order to handle updated data that is passed to children through templates.**, like when you use [selectedContact]="whatever"

In component that is supposed to receive the selected contact, first implement the right interface OnChanges:

```
export class ChatroomComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
   // do stuff ...

   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
     if (changes?.selectedContact) {
       this.selectedContact = changes.selectedContact.currentValue
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: This is totally fine and should do the job. If you have more data you want to share between components, I would recommend checking out the NGRX Store and/or the NGRX component store.